# How to navigate to a different website with tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, reddit

A while ago reddit changed their notification system to be worse. However the old, better version is still accessible through /message/inbox. I wanted to create a tampermonkey script, that allowed me to use the old version, without manually having to switch to it. I managed to make this:

```
var $ = window.jQuery;

function changeLink(){
if(window.location.href=='https://www.reddit.com/notifications'){window.location.assign('https://www.reddit.com/message/inbox');}
}

$(document).click(function()
{
setTimeout(changeLink,1);
});
```

Which does work, but is extremely inelegant, and obviously leads to the page being a bit slower to load, because it needs to go to the wrong page first, before then switching to the right one. Ideally it wouldn't even go the wrong one in the first place. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Figure out the places that clicks result in a redirect to `/notification`, block the clicks when they happen, then navigate to `/message/inbox`. Can't say exactly how without seeing the site's code.

Comment: A note for others: setting the `<a>` tag's href to `https://www.reddit.com/message/inbox` doesn't work, since new Reddit uses react-router.